# What is the value for $z+\frac{(50-z-x)}{2}=25$

Tags: polynomials

i've been trying an equation but don't know if the answer is right or wrong.

If anyone can help me figure out if it is right or wrong that will be a great help.

Thanks

The equation is as follows:
$$z+\frac{(50-z-x)}{2} =25$$
or can be written as:
$$z+\frac{(50-z-x)}{2} = 25$$

The answer i am getting is:

$$\frac{2z+2{(50-z-x)}}{2}=25$$

$2z+100-2z-2x = 50$

$100-2x = 50$

$-2x = 50-100$

$-2x = -50$

$x = 25$

Is it the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}z+\frac{50-z-x}{2} &= 25 \\ 2z + 50 - z - x &= 50 \\ z-x&=0 \\ z&=x \end{align} $

Comment: Why 2 is not multiplied by (50-z-x) ?

Comment: @980stack do you know how to do $1/2 + 1$

Comment: hey @980stack , yes it did, but the expression is (50-z-x)/2, hence the 2 in the denominator got cancelled with this 2 being multiplied throughout.

Comment: Oh my bad Thanks!